# ¿Como obtener las ocurrencias de horas en un string?

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo las siguiente cadena:

```
string horas = "Sabado 08:00 a.m. Domingo 14:00pm";
string horas_1 = "Sabado 7:00am Domingo 18:00 p.m";
```

Lo que necesito es obtener las horas que están en la cadena

en el primer caso 08:00 y 14:00
en el segundo caso 7:00 y 18:00

Lo intente con el siguiente codigo:

```
string pattern = @"^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$";

string aux_1 = "SABADO 08:00 a.m. DOMINGO 14:00pm";

MatchCollection matchedHours = Regex.Matches(aux_1, pattern);

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(aux_1, pattern))
{
  if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 0)
  {
    var text = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
  }
}
```

Sin embargo no obtengo nada.
**Como podría lograr sacar las horas de la cadena?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en los caracteres:

- `^`: Coincide con el inicio de una cadena
- `$`: Coincide con el final de una cadena

En otras palabras, si yo pongo cualquier cosa entre `^` y `$`, estoy indicando que quiero encontrar solamente las cadenas que coincidan como un todo con mi expresión regular. Lo que quieres hacer, es justamente lo contrario, encontrar todas las coincidencias dentro de cada cadena.

Por lo tanto, basta con remover esos caracteres de tu expresión y encontrarás las horas:

```
string pattern = @"([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"; //<- ojo, sin ^$

string aux_1 = "SABADO 08:00 a.m. DOMINGO 14:00pm";

MatchCollection matchedHours = Regex.Matches(aux_1, pattern);

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(aux_1, pattern))
{
  if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 0)
  {
    var text = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
  }
}
```

Para completar la idea, yo también puedo iniciar una expresión con `^`, por ejemplo:

```
string pattern = @"^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]";
```

Va a encontrar una coincidencia en todas aquellas cadenas que inicien con una hora (sin importar como terminen).

Por otro lado, también puedo terminar con `$`, por ejemplo:

```
string pattern = @"([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$";
```

Va a encontrar una coincidencia en todas aquellas cadenas que terminen con una hora (sin AM o PM), sin importar como hayan iniciado.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar la siguiente [regEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp): `/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/g`.

Donde esperas el formato `HH:MM` ó `H:MM`, entonces:

- Para `HH` o `H` se evalua que sean números y puede ser 1 ó 2
  dígitos(consecutivos).
- Para `:` simplemente tal cual.
- Para `MM` se evalua también que sean números y tienen que ser 2 dígitos(consecutivos).

La demo está hecha en **js** pero la regEx es la misma y la puedes aplicar en **c#**.

```js
const horas = "Sabado 08:00 a.m. Domingo 14:00pm";
const horas_1 = "Sabado 7:00am Domingo 18:00 p.m";

const regEx = /[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/g;

console.log("horas => ", horas.match(regEx));
console.log("horas_1 => ", horas_1.match(regEx));
```

Comment: Esta bien, sin embargo no controla el maximo de 23:59, si coloco 30:00 igual lo extrae.